# ajax error response in xamarin.ios

Tags: ajax, xamarin.ios

i make app ios using xamarin.ios and use webview 
in .chtml file call webservice using ajax as following code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {       
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://www.chc-sa.com/webService/AboutUs',
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //do something about the error
               document.getElementById("net").textContent = "Network Error";
            },
            success: function (response, $Id) {
                //do something with response
                document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = response.Details.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
            }
        });

        //-----------------------------------

    });
</script>
```

code always fire error not excute success
and code work fine in xamarin.android or windowsphone
but in xamarin .ios when run it in simulator mac show error only

is there some configuration in xamarin.ios to execute ajax code correctly? or in iphone mobile?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: function error only fires but i can not get type of error :(

Comment: can you help me ? @Jason